# What have duplicated values in sorted array changed value

Tags: java, arrays

I attempted the the leetcode question: **Remove Duplicates from Sorted Array**
When input was 1,1,1,3,5,5,7 , my output was 1,3,5,7. I got it right and was happy. But out of curiosity I wanted to see what the full array looked now that I moved duplicates to the end of array.
I got 1,3,5,7,5,5,7
I expected 1,3,5,7,1,1,5

In the removeDuplicate method

```java
int n = nums.length;
int result = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    if(i < n - 1 && nums[i] == nums[i + 1]) {
        continue;
    }
    nums[result++] = nums[i];
}
return result;
```

In main:

```java
int [] numbers = {1,1,1,3,5,5,7};
int res = rd.removeDuplicates(numbers);
for(int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
    System.out.print(numbers[i]);
}
```

Why have the duplicates values changed?

Comment: Surround both sides from && symbol in () to ensure correct operator precedence

Comment: Can not see where you are pushing duplicates to the end. Simple the "rest" of the array stays the same (5,5,7),

Comment: You are copying unique elements to the beginning of the array, leaving the right part of the array intact. Why do you expect `1,3,5,7,1,1,5`?

Comment: Thanks Peter and Aivean you both make sense.

Comment: I suggest adding `System.out.println(nums)` inside the `for` loop in `removeDuplicate`. Then you can see the change to the array at each step.

Comment: Thanks code apprentice